# SQL Server Invalid Object Name

Tags: sql-server-2012

SQL Server error say `Invalid Object Name` for my query but same query running another same copy database. I think very interesting.

My query like this;

```
exec sp_executesql 
   N'SELECT * 
     FROM [dbo].[VwSysUser] 
     WHERE SysUserName = @SysUserName 
       AND Password = @Password 
       AND TypeAccountStatusID = @TypeAccountStatusID',
   N'@SysUserName nvarchar(5), @Password nvarchar(7), @TypeAccountStatusID int', 
     @SysUserName = N'admin', @Password = N'e185700', @TypeAccountStatusID = 1
```

and I try this solution but no change,

http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBProgramming/how-to-refresh-the-local-intellisense-ca

Thanks

Comment: Are you running the query in the correct database? Does `VwSysUser` exist? Is you database case-sensitive? There are [many questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+server+invalid+object+name) about this error already.

Comment: Absolutly exist. 

I execute same query another 'same' db no problem.

Comment: If the query works in one database but not in the other then it's unlikely that they're really the same

Comment: I Backup and Restore database, everything same.

Comment: Yeah but almost we use the db 6 years.

Comment: Sometimes the same thing is happening in using the site. The problem is solved by restart the database. But this is not good and stabil solution.

Comment: What is the full error message including the name of the invalid object? I'm guessing that `VwSysUser` is a view, what objects does it reference? It's possible that an object referenced by the view is being dropped or modified. If so, [`sp_refreshview`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187821.aspx) might solve the problem. And have you used SQL Profiler to check that the SQL being sent to the database is what you expect?

Comment: Sir thank you for your help. Yes its a view and i have the profiler. Just i good backup the db and restored. No change any change. However if i restart the MSSQLSERVER service its ok solved. But it can happen any moment